# Get what page the visitor visit in PHP

Tags: php

I was trying to get what page the visitor visit:

Here is my code:

```
$url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$urlcomplete = $url;
$url = explode(".com/",$url);
$urlcount = count($url);
$newurl = '';
for ($start = 1; $start < $urlcount; $start++) {
    if ($newurl != '') {
        $newurl .= '.com/'; 
    }
    $newurl .= $url[$start];    
}
$url = explode('/',$newurl);
$urlcount = explode('?',end($url));
$url[count($url) - 1] = $urlcount[0];
$urlcount = count($url);
```

By using the code above, all the subpage will be store in the $url.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

```
$url[0] = 'questions'
$url[1] = 'ask'
```

Just want to ask, is this good way, or there are others better way?

Comment: You need a regex here. What happens when you have a non `.com` domain?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in human terms?

Comment: What part of the url from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask are you trying to obtain.

Comment: if you only need the URI structure after the TLD you can use $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] so you only get "question/ask" and parse this for your needs.

Comment: @s_ha_dum i trying to get what page and sub folder does the visitor visit now.

Comment: @AdamMagaluk i want to get 'questions' and 'ask'

Comment: @godesign Yeah. the solution give by Ilmari Karonen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prepending `SERVER_NAME` to the `REQUEST_URI`, and then trying to split it off, is pointless.  This should be a simpler solution:

```
# first, split off the query string, if any:
list( $path ) = explode( '?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2 );

# then just split the URL path into its components:
$url = explode( '/', ltrim( $path, '/' ) );
```

The `ltrim` removes any leading slashes from the path, so that `$url[0]` won't be empty.

Note that there might still be an empty element at the end of the `$url` array, if the path ends in a slash.  You *could* get rid of it by using `trim` instead of `ltrim`, but you may not want to, since the trailing slash is significant for things like resolving relative URLs.